Which conditions are necessary to enable the Event Monitor functionality?
I would like to confirm which conditions are necessary to enable the Event Monitor functionality.
Currently, I can only see the sandbox environment, and under Company Information, I noticed that the org has 10 Event Monitoring Analytics Apps Permission Set Licenses, but none of them are assigned to any users.
My profile is System Administrator, and I have the View Event Log Files, View Real-Time Event Monitoring Data, and Customize Application permissions checked. In the sandbox, we are able to generate event log files and enable streaming real-time events.
I'm confused because I haven’t been assigned any licenses related to event monitoring, yet I can still use the event monitor. Does having the permissions to View Event Log Files, View Real-Time Event Monitoring Data, and Customize Application automatically imply that the org has Event Monitor functionality?
Thank you!

As per this article , event monitoring can only be made accessible by Salesforce.

Since it is accessible on sandbox, it means that is available on
production from which the sandbox was created/refreshed.
Having permissions for event monitoring related features does not
imply that feature is enabled in the org. A better way of checking if
event monitoring is enabled in the org would be to check for the
presence of Event Monitoring Analytics Apps Admin permission set.

Also , we can check if event monitoring is enabled using below steps:

Navigate to Setup
Access Event Monitoring settings by searching for Event Monitoring Settings in quick find box
Check the Generate event log files feature flag. If it's enabled, it means that event monitoring is enabled for the org.

For managing the event monitoring app , there is a special type of
admin permission explained here. Event monitoring admin has many permissions that just viewing its objects as explained in the link.
Below link provides a detailed guide to setup event monitoring :
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_help_setup_admin_wave_permissions.htm&type=5
